# On AWS Cloudfront, I'd like to route /api/* requests to an external api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm fairly new to Cloudfront ( AWS in general ), and looking set up a behaviour such that any requests that is for example

`test.com/api/*`

goes to an existing api that we also own, except it's on a seperate domain, e.g.

`staging.test.com/api`

Is this an allowed behaviour? I probably will need to allow for this the receiving API in CORS but just looking for how to set this up as a behaviour in **Cloudfront**.

I have tried using lambda functions along with the route

e.g.

```
    
    var response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers:
            { "location": { "value": "https://staging.test.com.au/api/" + redirectPath } }
        }

    return response;
```

That doesn't seem to be working.

So was just wondering what is the correct way of going about this, I can only find references on using an API gateway instead which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `origin` and `behavior`. Define origin for and `staging.test.com/api` and add new behavior with path pattern as `/api/*`.

Details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html?icmpid=docs_cf_help_panel#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

Comment: Heya thanks, we ended up solving this, basically the way you suggested but we had a load balancer that sat in front of our API so we ended up pointing it to that as our origin which worked.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked out for you. :)